# Directory with correct permissions is not writable

Tags: backup, time-machine, high-sierra, permission

I installed high sierra on a new machine and then copied over some  directories inside my home from my time machine external disk.

The backup was created with another machine and os version from a user having the same name of the one recently created on the new installation.

90% of the things went ok.

For unknown reasons some subdirectories of my home (copied from the backup) are not writable.

I have tried every possible combination of chmod commands, and in theory everything should work correctly:

- cmd+i, general:

  - item not locked
  - item not shared
- cmd+i, sharing and permission:

  - myuser: Read and Write
  - staff: Read Only
  - everyone: Read Only
- `stat` shows:

  - Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  501/     myuser)   Gid: (   20/   staff)
  - 501 is the correct id my current user

I think it's not a unix permission problem as the permissions should work as is.

I've also tried `chflags nouchg my_folder` with no luck.

Not sure what could cause this.

Comment: What does `ls -leO@d` on them show?

Comment: Does this command produce any output? - `sudo find "$HOME" ! -user "$(id -un)"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've cd into my_folder then executed the command `ls -leO@d` that produced: `drwxr-xr-x+ 20 myuser  staff  - 640 May  6 11:26 .`  
`0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown`. I suspect that 'everyone deny' is the culprit here

Comment: @fd0 that command didn't produce any output

Comment: Well, that's good. It confirms you own all the files in your home folder.

Answer (score 1):

Write permission could be blocked by file/folder modes, user flags, non-ownership, Access Control Lists (ACLs) and/or extended attributes.  Below are some commands which can fix these types of errors.

> Note: I assume `my_folder` does not contain any symbolic links. If there are symbolic links, then these commands ***may*** need to be modified.

You can recursively change the folders mode to 755 (drwxr-xr-x) by using the command given below.

```
find my_folder -type d -execdir chmod 755 {} \;
```

You can recursively change the regular files mode to 644 (-rw-r--r--) by using the command given below.

```
find my_folder -type f -execdir chmod 644 {} \;
```

You can recursively remove user flags by using the command given below.

```
sudo chflags -R nouchg,nohidden,noopaque,dump,nouappnd my_folder
```

You can recursively change user ownership of the files and folders by using the command given below.

```
sudo chown -R $USER my_folder
```

You can recursively change the group of the files and folders to `staff` by using the command given below.

```
sudo chgrp -R staff my_folder
```

You can recursively remove any Access Control Lists (ACLs) by using the command given below.

```
chmod -RN my_folder
```

You can recursively remove any extended attributes by using the command given below.

```
xattr -rc my_folder
```

Often searching for locked files and/or folders can be useful. Below is a command for this.

```
find my_folder -flags +uchg -exec ls -dF {} \;
```

Comment: `chmod -RN my_folder` seems to work, all other commands did nothing